# Python code coverage on p4 diff

Tags: python, diff, code-coverage, perforce

I am running python unit test cases and collecting coverage using python's coverage command, http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/.

Most of my code is change in existing files, there were no test cases written in past for the same file. And the aim is just to over diff, the section of code that has changed. Also need to report how many lines were there, how many covered, how many missing, and % line numbers covered form a diff file.

Is there a tool that can show coverage report on a diff of a file, specifically p4 diff or change number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[diff-cover](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/diff_cover/0.6.0) provides coverage reporting for a single commit, although in Git.  It's open-source, you may be able to adapt it to your needs, or even contribute Perforce support.

Answer (score 0):

You might try my (very rough around the edges; release early!) tool `cuv-ner` which has a subcommand `cuv diff` which will syntax-highlight and colour your diff by coverage data -- it can deal with straight "diff" output, or "git diff" output. If it doesn't work for "whatever perforce outputs" please file a bug :)

https://meejah.ca/projects/cuvner